# Trouble reading in Unicode strings from CSV file to DictReader in Python

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary, unicode, codec

I have a CSV file I'm trying to read in using DictReader.

But doing just this:

```
with("BeerRatings.csv", "r", "utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        print line
```

gives me some ugly unicode as such:

```
{'Rating': '4', 'Brewery': 'Tr\xc3\xb6egs Brewing Company', 'Beer name': 'Tr\xc3\xb6egs Hopback Amber Ale'}
{'Rating': '4.59', 'Brewery': 'Brasserie Dieu Du Ciel', 'Beer name': 'P\xc3\xa9ch\xc3\xa9 Mortel - Bourbon Barrel Aged'} etc.
```

So, reading on stackoverflow, I editted my code to this, using the codecs module:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open("BeerRatings.csv", "r", "utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        print line
```

But this is giving me a `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xea' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)`.

Any tips on how to go fix this?

UPDATE aka more flailing around:

```
def UnicodeDictReader(utf8_data, **kwargs):
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(utf8_data, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield {key: unicode(value, 'utf-8') for key, value in row.iteritems()}

with open("BeerRatings.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = UnicodeDictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        print line
```

THis still gives me a less than ideal output...

```
{'Rating': u'4', 'Brewery': u'Tr\xf6egs Brewing Company', 'Beer name': u'Tr\xf6egs Hopback Amber Ale'}
{'Rating': u'4.59', 'Brewery': u'Brasserie Dieu Du Ciel', 'Beer name': u'P\xe9ch\xe9 Mortel - Bourbon Barrel Aged'}
```

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: Try using the last example for Unicode Writer and Reader on [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples)

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha - tried making appropriate changes (look at my post update) but to no avail... any suggestions?

Comment: Well, I think that is expected, please check the encoding of the console.

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha - what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80606/discussion-between-vikas-neha-ojha-and-spicyclubsauce).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `csv` module in Python 2.X expects the input file to be opened in binary, and does not support encodings.  It is, however, compatible with UTF-8, but you have to decode to Unicode yourself:

```
import csv

with open('BeerRatings.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        for k,v in line.iteritems():
            print k.decode('utf8'),':',v.decode('utf8')
        print
```

Output:

```
Rating : 4
Brewery : Tröegs Brewing Company
Beer name : Tröegs Hopback Amber Ale

Rating : 4.59
Brewery : Brasserie Dieu Du Ciel
Beer name : Péché Mortel - Bourbon Barrel Aged
```

#### Edit

Per your `UnicodeDictReader`, you still need to print the key/value pairs as I did or you get the default printing for a `dict`, which shows escaped data via the `repr()` of the string.  Also open in binary mode.  It matters on some OSes, particularly Windows.

```
import csv

def UnicodeDictReader(utf8_data, **kwargs):
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(utf8_data, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield {key.decode('utf8'):value.decode('utf8') for key, value in row.iteritems()}

def prettydict(D):
    return u'{' + u', '.join(u"'{}': '{}'".format(k,v) for k,v in D.iteritems()) + u'}'

with open("BeerRatings.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = UnicodeDictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        print prettydict(line)
```

Output:

```
{'Rating': '4', 'Brewery': 'Tröegs Brewing Company', 'Beer name': 'Tröegs Hopback Amber Ale'}
{'Rating': '4.59', 'Brewery': 'Brasserie Dieu Du Ciel', 'Beer name': 'Péché Mortel - Bourbon Barrel Aged'}
```

Comment: I think the bottom of your code is incomplete - did you want to print something else? And also, I was trying to preserve the single-line entry format - best way to do that?

Comment: No, it was just a blank line between dictionaries.

Comment: Mark - thanks for the good info. Can we change the code though so that the output is in the same format as the original? (all in a single line)

Comment: with your editted ` UnicodeDictReader` function, why does `with open("BeerRatings.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = UnicodeDictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        print line` not give us the desired output?

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce, Python objects have two ways to display: a "pretty" way via `str()` and a debugging way via `repr()`.  `repr()` escapes non-ASCII bytes so you can see exactly what is in the string.  This is the default used by `list` and `dict` items.  You have to roll your own display if you don't want the default.  I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce, by the way, Python 3 displays as you'd expect.

Comment: could you do an example with dict comprehension as well for this situation? would be much appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80608/discussion-between-spicyclubsauce-and-mark-tolonen).